# Rollup expose multiple global names

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

How can I expose multiple global names?

```
// src/module1.js
const Util = {
  func1 () {},
  func2 () {},
  func3 () {}
}

export default Util
```

```
// src/module2.js
import Util from './module2'

class Class1 {
  constructor({ foo = 1, bar = Util.func1 }) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  method1() {}
  method2() {}
  method3() {}
}

export default Class1
```

```
// src/index.js
import Util from './module1.js'
import Class1 from './module2.js'

export default { Util, Class1 }
```

How to configure Rollup to expose both `Util` and `Calss1` to the global space so I can consume it like

```
// Util.func1 is the default

const a = new Class1({ foo: 5, bar: Util.func2 }); 
a.method1();
```

Comment: What module format are you targetting?

Comment: @Bergi I'm planning to bundle it as umd

Comment: I don't think rollup supports that yet, but you could make a feature request. Until then, just `import * as module from '…'; Object.assign(window, module)` or `… ({Util, Class1} = module); // global assignment`.